# collect hmtl text and submit for translation?

Tags: javascript

i have a requirement where i have to collect all the innertext from all the the html elements and then send it to php. At the backend, once these texts are received and translated into another language via some third party library, i need to bring the translated response back and update all the changes. I am not clear, as to how to achieve this? how to get all the element's text content and once the translation is over and i get the data in the clientside, how will i be able to update respective elements? I mean how to know where to insert which text?
suppose

```
     hello <span>world </span>
     <p> its a bright and sunny day </p>
   </div>
```

now, my question is that , to translate the contents of the snippet, i have to collect its textContents. can anybody help and point me in the right direction.
i need to create a json string like this
"{"hello","world","its a bright nad sunny day"}"
how to achieve this?

Comment: Can you provide us with some code?

Comment: yes i did. can you look into it

Answer (score 0):

You need to traverse the body recursively:

```js
var a=[];
function getChildText(e){
   e.childNodes.forEach(c=>{
      if (c.nodeType==c.TEXT_NODE){
         let t = c.textContent.trim();
         if (t) a.push(t);
      } else if (c.tagName!="SCRIPT") getChildText(c);
   });
}
getChildText(document.body);
console.log(a);
```

```html
<div>
     hello <span>world </span>
     <p> its a bright and sunny day </p>
   </div>
```

Use MutationObserver:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <script>
       var languages = ['en','fr','de'];

       var translations = {
       "___000___":["Best Web Translator","Meilleur traducteur Web","Bester Webübersetzer"],
       "___001___":["Welcome to the Best Translator of the Web","Bienvenue chez le meilleur traducteur du Web","Willkommen beim besten Übersetzer im Web"],
       "___002___":["Do you have something to translate today?","Avez-vous quelque chose à traduire aujourd'hui?","Haben Sie heute etwas zu übersetzen?"],
       "___003___":["Seriously I can help you.","Sérieusement, je peux vous aider.","Im Ernst, ich kann dir helfen."],
        }
        var langInd = languages.indexOf((new URLSearchParams(location.search)).get('lang'));
        if (langInd==-1) langInd = 0;
        function translateNode(n){
            let t = n.textContent;
            if (n.childNodes.length>0) for (let nn of n.childNodes) translateNode(nn);
            else if (t.includes("___")){
                let ti = t.substring(t.indexOf("___"),t.lastIndexOf("___")+3);
                if (translations[ti]) n.textContent = t.replace(ti,translations[ti][langInd]);
            }

        }
        function translator(mutations){
            for (let m of mutations){
                for (let n of m.addedNodes) translateNode(n);
            }
        }
        (new MutationObserver(translator)).observe(document, {childList:true, attributes:true, characterData:true, subtree:true});
   </script>
    <title>___000___</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>___001___</h1>
    <div>
        <p>___002___</p>
        <strong>___003___</strong>
    </div>
</body></html>
```

This piece of code retrieves the query string in the URL (ie. lang) and decides which language to translate into.

You have to modify the code a bit to adapt to your server, possibly downloading a periodically compiled translations data file.

Comment: i hvae updated my question. can you look into it once?

Comment: @midorima there you go